# Fn-Lock not working on external keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have an external keyboard connected to my laptop (easier usage). But the problem is Fn-lock function does nothing. On my laptop pressing Fn-Lock would allow me to access the other keys without holding down fn key.

On this external keyboard, to access the Fn keys, I must **hold down** the Function key and press what I need. Yes I realise I can inverse it on the BIOS but my laptop keyboard is the opposite (FN key by default, whilst this external keyboard is **not** fn by default)

Is there a way to hold the Fn key when Fn-Lock doesn't work?

Comment: Fn key combos are initiated within the keyboard itself, not in the computer. If the external keyboard has no dedicated Fn-Lock button, it cannot do it. This is a no-fix situation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @gronostaj - I was kind of waiting for confirmation from the OP that it was indeed the case that the external has no lock button, but sure, it's a fair assumption. Will do.

Answer (score 3):

To turn a brief comment into a brief answer…

Fn key combos are initiated within the keyboard itself, not in the computer. If the external keyboard has no dedicated Fn-Lock button, it cannot do it.

This is a no-fix situation.

Comment: Ah, I understand thank you for the easy explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I figured somebody else could use this piece of advice: There's actually a software fix for this.

https://github.com/okkosh/FN-key-lock

I had the same problem and it worked for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).